# How do i make a drop down list to accept user input values in perl cgi script

Tags: perl, cgi

I have a perl cgi script that has a simple drop down list of values for the user to select for a field meterSize.

But now i have a new requirement to allow the user to input/enter a value if its missing in the drop down list.

Is it possible?

Can you please tell me if i can do this with my current design or provide any pointers? links? Thanks in advance.

Code-2 is the subroutine implementation for the drop down list.  Code-1 is how i call the subroutine.

Explaination:

meterSize is coming out of a db query and passed to subroutine which implements the drop-down list for it from a known list of values.

Code-1:

$value = drop_down_mSize("Meter Size","meterSize",$job->{meterSize});

Code-2:

```
sub drop_down_mSize {

    my $local_label = shift;
    my $local_name = shift;
    my $db_eq_val = shift;
    my %local_var = ( "15mm" => "15mm", "20mm" => "20mm", "25mm" => "25mm", "40mm" => "40mm", "50mm" => "50mm", "80mm" => "80mm", "100mm" => "100mm", "125mm" => "125mm", " " => " ", NULL => "NULL");
    my $return;

    $return .= "<td>$local_label</td><td>";
    $return .= "<select name = '$local_name' id = '$local_name'>";
    foreach(sort keys%local_var)
    {
            if($db_eq_val eq $_)
            {
                    $return .= "<option selected value=\"$_\">$local_var{$_}</option>";
            }
            else
            {
                    $return .= "<option value=\"$_\">$local_var{$_}</option>";
            }
    }
    $return .= "</select>";
    $return .= "</td>";
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: I don't believe you can do this with straight HTML, but you could look at jquery-ui [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox).

Answer (score 0):

> But now i have a new requirement to allow the user to input/enter a
>   value if its missing in the drop down list.
>
> Is it possible?

Of course:

create_form.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI; 
use CGI::Carp qw{ fatalsToBrowser };


#Starting data:
my $local_label = 'Choose a size:';
my $local_name = 'size_select';
my $db_eq_val = '20mm';
my @sizes = ( "15mm", "20mm", "25mm"); 

my $cgi = CGI->new;

print $cgi->header, 
      $cgi->start_html('My Size Page'),

      $cgi->start_form(
          -method => 'post',
          -action => '/cgi-bin/process_form.pl',
      ),
      $cgi->div(
          $cgi->label({-for=>$local_name}, $local_label),
          $cgi->popup_menu(  #select() is a perl butilin funciton, so 'popup_menu" is the function name
              -name     => $local_name,
              -id       => $local_name,
              -values   => \@sizes,
              -default  => $db_eq_val  #If the default isn't in options, then first option will be selected
          ),
      ),

      $cgi->div(
          $cgi->label({-for=>'size_text_box'}, "If desired size isn't up there, enter it here:"),
          $cgi->input({
              -type => 'text', 
              -id   => 'size_text_box',
              -name => 'size_text_box'
          }),
      ),



      $cgi->submit('Submit', 'submit'),
      $cgi->end_form,

      $cgi->end_html();
```

Here's the html that code creates:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>My Size Page</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="/cgi-bin/2cgi.pl" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div><label for="size_select">Choose a size:</label> <select name="size_select"  id="size_select">
<option value="15mm">15mm</option>
<option selected="selected" value="20mm">20mm</option>
<option value="25mm">25mm</option>
</select></div><div><label for="size_text_box">If desired size isn't up there, enter it here:</label> <input name="size_text_box" type="text" id="size_text_box" /></div><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="submit" /></form>
</body>
</html>
```

process_form.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI; 
use CGI::Carp qw{ fatalsToBrowser };

my $cgi = CGI->new;

my $text_box = $cgi->param('size_text_box');
#If the textbox has a value, ignore the select:
my $output = $text_box ? 
             $text_box : 
             $cgi->param('size_select');

print $cgi->header,
      $cgi->start_html('Results Page'),
      $cgi->div("The size you chose was: $output"),
      $cgi->end_html;
```

However, the modern way is to use a template.  Here it is with Template Toolkit:

create_form.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw{ fatalsToBrowser };
use Template;

my $local_label = 'Choose a size:';
my $local_name = 'size_select';
my $db_eq_val = '20mm';
my @sizes = ( "15mm", "20mm", "25mm"); 


my $vars = {
   select_label => $local_label,
   select_name  => $local_name,
   default      => $db_eq_val,
   sizes        => \@sizes,
};

my $tname = 'templates/form.html';

my $template = Template->new({
    INCLUDE_PATH => '/Users/7stud/perl_programs/cgi_projects/1proj',
});

$template->process($tname, $vars)
    or die "*MY* template process failed: ", $template->error(), "\n";
```

According to the [docs](http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/modules/Template.html#method_process):

> The process() method is called to process a template. The first
>   parameter indicates the input template as one of:
>
> 1. a filename relative
>      to INCLUDE_PATH, if defined
> 2. ....

and more [docs](http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Config.html#section_Template_Files_and_Blocks):

> ...each of the INCLUDE_PATH directories is searched in turn to locate the template file.

templates/form.html:

```
[% INCLUDE templates/header.html
   title = "Results page"
%]


<form action="/cgi-bin/process_form.pl" method="post">

  <label for="[% select_name %]">[% select_label %]</label>
  <select id="[% select_name %]" name="[% select_name %]">
    [% FOREACH size IN sizes %]
      [% IF size == default %]
        <option selected="selected" value="[% size %]">[% size %]</option>
      [% ELSE %]
        <option value="[% size %]">[% size %]</option>
      [% END %]
    [% END %]
  </select>

  <div>
    <label for="size_text_box">If you didn't see the size above, enter one here:</label>
    <input type="text" id="size_text_box" name="size_text_box">
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </div>

</form>



[% INCLUDE templates/footer.html%]
```

templates/header.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>[% title %]</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
```

templates/footer.html:

```
<div>mysite.com</div>
</body>
</html>
```

process_form.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI; 
use CGI::Carp qw{ fatalsToBrowser };
use Template;

my $cgi = CGI->new;

my $text_box = $cgi->param('size_text_box');
#If the textbox has a value, ignore the select:
my $result = $text_box ? 
             $text_box : 
             $cgi->param('size_select');

my $vars = {
    chosen_size => $result,
};

my $tname = 'templates/results.html';
my $template = Template->new({
    INCLUDE_PATHS => '/Users/7stud/perl_programs/cgi_projects/1proj',
});
$template->process($tname, $vars)
    or die "**MY** template process failed", $template->error(), "\n";
```

templates/results.html:

```
[% INCLUDE templates/header.html
   title = "Results Page"
%]

<div>You chose: [% chosen_size %]</div>

[% INCLUDE templates/footer.html %]
```

The directory structure:

```
$ tree 1proj/
1proj/
├── cgi-bin
│   ├── create_form.pl
│   ├── process_form.pl
│   └── simple_cgi.pl
├── serverHTTP.py (yes, a python server!)
└── templates
    ├── footer.html
    ├── form.html
    ├── header.html
    ├── results.html
    └── xform.html

2 directories, 9 files
```

serverHTTP.py:

```
#python2:

import BaseHTTPServer
import CGIHTTPServer

PORT = 8000
handler = CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler

httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(("", PORT), handler)

print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()


'''
#python3:
import http.server

PORT = 8000
handler = http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler

httpd = http.server.HTTPServer(("", PORT), handler)

print("serving at port", PORT)
httpd.serve_forever()
'''
```

You just have to put that server in any directory from which you want to serve files (that directory will be the server root `/`, so the path to files in that directory will be `/some_file.html`).  Then start the server:

```
$ python serverHTTP.py
```

By default, files in a sub directory named `cgi-bin/` will be executed, and you can send requests to scripts using url's like the following in your browser:

```
http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/create_form.html
```

In your html files, you would use paths like:

```
<form action="/cgi-bin/process_form.html" method="post">
```

Comment: FYI, the CGI docs say that [HTML Generation functions should no longer be used](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#HTML-Generation-functions-should-no-longer-be-used): *"All HTML generation functions within CGI.pm are no longer being maintained. Any issues, bugs, or patches will be rejected unless they relate to fundamentally broken page rendering...The rationale for this is that the HTML generation functions of CGI.pm are an obfuscation at best and a maintenance nightmare at worst. You should be using a template engine for better separation of concerns."*

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, 1) Those are not the CGI docs. The CGI docs say no such thing. 2) The op said they were using CGI, 3) I am working on a template example to show the op what they should be doing, but the !#@#!#$!@# template system I chose won't @!#$@#!$ work. OKAY?!!!

Comment: 1) I linked to the docs for the latest version of CGI, 4.13, released on December 18, 2014. They do not match the docs on perldoc.perl.org because the version of CGI included in core is older. 2) The part I quoted doesn't say "don't use CGI," it says "don't use the HTML generation functions" (although CGI is being [removed from core](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#CGI.pm-HAS-BEEN-REMOVED-FROM-THE-PERL-CORE)). 3) Relax. I'm just trying to give you some information on a recent change that you may not have been aware of.